# algebraic derivation-simplification using the lag operator

Tags: time-series, lags

Hi All: I am asking this with the hope that somebody knows how to simplify an expression which is composed of lag operators.

First, the straightforward ones:

So,  if I have say, $\frac{y_{t}}{\left(1-\rho L\right)}$ then, assuming that $\rho L$ is less than 1.0 and  using the formula for infinite geometric series, the term simplifies to
$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \rho^{i} y_{t-i}$.

Another straightforward example is if you have the term, $y_{t}(1-L)$, then, by the definition of the lag operator, that equals $y_{t} - y_{t-1}$.

Or, another example is if you have $\frac{y_{t}}{\left(1-L^{n}\right)}$ then it can be shown that this simplifies to $\sum_{i=0}^\infty y_{t-(i \times n)}$. So you end up with an infinite sum but only every $n$th term is in the sum.

But I get confused when I have say a combination of all 3 examples of the above in one expression. For example,

$\frac{y_{t} (1-L)}{\left(1 - L^{n}\right)\left(1 - \rho L\right)}$

Does the above simplify to something simpler ? Thanks.

Or, if someone knows of a reference where simplifying expressions such as these is explained or examples are given, that would be just as useful. Thanks again.

Comment: You can cancel out $(1-L)$ from both the numerator and the denominator, making the denominator less elegant.

Comment: Hi Richard: Could you explain in more detail what you mean ? I'm not clear on what can be cancelled. Thanks.

Comment: You can use long division to see what $\frac{1-L^n}{1-L}$ is and put that into the denominator. This will probably be a long expression. It is pretty standard, but I forgot what the answer is, so I would have to do the long division myself to tell you.

Comment: I was thinking of something along the following: ( Leaving out the (1−) term for a moment ). The numerator is the first difference and I showed in the example above that $(1−^n)$ sums every th observation. So, I'm thinking that that the result of that expression would be the nth difference but is it each $n$th difference so $(y_{t}−_{t-n}), (y_{t-1}−_{t-n-1})$, etc, or every nth first difference so $(y_{t-n} − y_{t-n−1})$, $(y_{t-2n} − y_{t-2n−1}) $, etc. I'm not sure. Thanks.